# Error calling Android layout in flutter - Activity/Fragment different from Linear/Relative/Frame layout

Tags: android, flutter, dart, channel

Friends, I'm trying to create a channel between android and flutter.

I'm getting this error when trying to call the Android layout in flutter:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> E/AndroidRuntime(30163): Process: com.example.monitoramento, PID: 30163
> E/AndroidRuntime(30163): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.monitoramento/com.example.monitoramento.DemoCamActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Root view of the activity/fragment cannot be other than Linear/Relative/Frame layout

This is my MainActivity class:

```
package com.example.monitoramento;
import android.content.Intent;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

    public static final String CHANNEL = "flutter.rortega.com.basicchannelcommunication";

    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
        new MethodChannel(getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(),
                CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(new MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull MethodChannel.Result result) {
                if(call.method.equals("showNativeView")){
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DemoCamActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    result.success(true);
                }else{
                    result.notImplemented();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the DemoActivity:

```
package com.example.monitoramento;/*
 * Copyright 2016 Keval Patel.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;


import com.example.androidhiddencamera.CameraConfig;
import com.example.androidhiddencamera.CameraError;
import com.example.androidhiddencamera.HiddenCameraActivity;
import com.example.androidhiddencamera.HiddenCameraUtils;
import com.example.androidhiddencamera.config.CameraFacing;
import com.example.androidhiddencamera.config.CameraFocus;
import com.example.androidhiddencamera.config.CameraImageFormat;
import com.example.androidhiddencamera.config.CameraResolution;
import com.example.androidhiddencamera.config.CameraRotation;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;

public class DemoCamActivity extends HiddenCameraActivity {
    private static final int REQ_CODE_CAMERA_PERMISSION = 1253;

    private CameraConfig mCameraConfig;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mCameraConfig = new CameraConfig()
                .getBuilder(this)
                .setCameraFacing(CameraFacing.FRONT_FACING_CAMERA)
                .setCameraResolution(CameraResolution.HIGH_RESOLUTION)
                .setImageFormat(CameraImageFormat.FORMAT_JPEG)
                .setImageRotation(CameraRotation.ROTATION_270)
                .setCameraFocus(CameraFocus.AUTO)
                .build();


        //Check for the camera permission for the runtime
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            //Start camera preview
            startCamera(mCameraConfig);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    REQ_CODE_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
        }

        int noOfSecond = 1;
        final Button btn1 = findViewById(R.id.capture_btn);
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //TODO Set your button auto perform click.
                btn1.performClick();
            }
        }, noOfSecond * 3000);

        //Take a picture
        findViewById(R.id.capture_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Take picture using the camera without preview.
                takePicture();
            }
        });
    }

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQ_CODE_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {

            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startCamera(mCameraConfig);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_camera_permission_denied, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } else {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] onImageCapture(@NonNull File imageFile) {
        // Convert file to bitmap.
        // Do something.
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), options);

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();

        //Display the image to the image view
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cam_prev)).setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        return byteArray;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraError(@CameraError.CameraErrorCodes int errorCode) {
        switch (errorCode) {
            case CameraError.ERROR_CAMERA_OPEN_FAILED:
                //Camera open failed. Probably because another application
                //is using the camera
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_cannot_open, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case CameraError.ERROR_IMAGE_WRITE_FAILED:
                //Image write failed. Please check if you have provided WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_cannot_write, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case CameraError.ERROR_CAMERA_PERMISSION_NOT_AVAILABLE:
                //camera permission is not available
                //Ask for the camera permission before initializing it.
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_cannot_get_permission, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case CameraError.ERROR_DOES_NOT_HAVE_OVERDRAW_PERMISSION:
                //Display information dialog to the user with steps to grant "Draw over other app"
                //permission for the app.
                HiddenCameraUtils.openDrawOverPermissionSetting(this);
                break;
            case CameraError.ERROR_DOES_NOT_HAVE_FRONT_CAMERA:
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.error_not_having_camera, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

What setting or feature can I use to resolve this issue?
My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.monitoramento">
   <application
        android:label="monitoramento"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
       <activity android:name=".DemoCamActivity"/>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I appreciate any comments!

Answer (score 0):

My error message was same but mine problem was just my Emulator was not getting internet from my laptop, I just restarted my emulator's data then the error was gone.